# Non-static properties in Partial class of System.Web.UI.Page getting reset in functions

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

The variables in the partial class _Default get reset in the function call as mentioned in the code below. But, on marking the properties as static, their values are retained.

My questions is, why does this happen? Doesn't each function call use same instance of page class?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public double ValueToConvert { get; set; }
    public double ConvertedValue { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    protected void btnUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //In this method, the non-static properties ValueToConvert and ConvertedValue
        //get reset. But why?
    }

}
```

Comment: Too lazy to create an answer but you need to look up on the viewstate.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't each function call use same instance of page class?

Well each *request* will create a new instance of the class. Heck, they could be on different processes or even different machines. If you have multiple method calls *within the same request* that will use the same instance, but otherwise you need to work out how you expect the state to be propagated. You could propagate it via the client (viewstate) or store it somewhere server-side (e.g. in a database).

Comment: Thanks, Jon! That explains it! Is there any way to mandate multiple calls within the same request?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet: You'd need to be more specific about what you mean by "multiple calls". Think carefully about the way the web works...

Comment: Jon, I realized [who](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) was actually answering my questions, and am totally humbled! Thanks, once more.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by using hiddenfields and wrapping them with the properties like this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public double ValueToConvert \
    { 
       get{
           return hfValueToConvert.Value;  
       }
       set{
           hfValueToConvert.Value = this.value.ToString();
       }
    }

    public double ConvertedValue
    { 
       get{
           return hfConvertedValue.Value;  
       }
       set{
           hfConvertedValue.Value = this.value.ToString();
       }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    protected void btnUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //In this method, the non-static properties ValueToConvert and ConvertedValue
        //get reset. But why?
    }

}
```

now add two HiddenField controls name **hfValueToConvert** & **hfConvertedValue** to your aspx page.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by using static variables. I just wanted to know why normal variables don't work.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet: *Don't* use static variables for this. Those variables will be shared between *all* requests, regardless of the client. I very much doubt that's what you want.